# How to suppress standard RadioButton check behavior in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, radio-button

I realize this one is a bit strange, so I'll explain. For a simple internet radio player I need a control to specify rating (1-5 "stars"). I have no experience or talent for graphical design, so all my attempts at drawing bitmaps look ridiculous/awful, take your pick. I couldn't find a 3rd party control with that functionality and look that fits standard VCL controls. So...

It occurred to me that I could achieve an OK look and consistency with Windows UI by using standard radiobuttons without captions, like this:

[image: radiobuttons without captions as a basic rating control]

I had a vague (and incorrect) recollection of a GroupIndex property; assigning a different value to each radiobutton would let multiple radiobuttons be checked at the same time. Alas, TRadioButton does not have a GroupIndex property, so that's that.

1. Is it possible to **completely override the natural radiobutton behavior**, so that more than one button can show up as checked at the same time? Or,
2. Can I **acquire all the bitmaps Windows uses for radiobuttons** (I assume they're bitmaps) from the system and draw them directly, including theming support? In this case I would still like to retain all the effects of a radiobutton, including the mouse hover "glow", etc, so that means getting all the "native" bitmaps and drawing them as necessary, perhaps on a TPaintBox.

Comment: Having multiple buttons checked concurrently is not "consistent" with the Windows UI. Why not use stars? There are plenty of icon libraries you can use.

Comment: I see your point (and Eugene's, below), but I would (weakly) argue that the radiobutton glyphs by themselves, without captions, don't look enough like true radiobuttons to be really confusing. A mouse hover effect would clarify the functionality. Perhaps I'm just deluding myself. As for icons, I have the IconExperience library, very nice, but drawing flat 16x16 stars does not look even remotely pleasing. I'd have to have the icons custom designed, which is beyond my means (I should probably preface all my questions: freeware, hobby projects, I've already spent enough on component libraries).

Comment: `GroupIndex` is for `TSpeedButton`, `TMenuItem`, and `TAction`. (Have you tried simply attaching actions to your radio buttons?)

Comment: You seem to be willing to do a lot of work just because you can't draw a star. Wouldn't it be easier to find a star that someone else drew, or have someone draw one for you? Here's one: [★](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm)

Comment: This is also a matter of convenience. Using separate `TRadioButton` s in separate `TPanel` s would be awkward, when it comes to displaying, setting, and reading the ratings. A custom control with a single `Rating` and `OnChange` property would be much simpler, as in my answer.

Comment: You could just use TAdvRangeSlider from TMS (http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advtrackbar.asp), for example, I'm sure there are many others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For maximum convenience, you could write a small control that draws native, themed, radio boxes:

```
unit StarRatingControl;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Messages, Graphics, Classes, Controls, UxTheme;

type
  TStarRatingControl = class(TCustomControl)
  private const
    DEFAULT_SPACING = 4;
    DEFAULT_NUM_STARS = 5;
    FALLBACK_BUTTON_SIZE: TSize = (cx: 16; cy: 16);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FRating: integer;
    FBuffer: TBitmap;
    FSpacing: integer;
    FNumStars: integer;
    FButtonStates: array of integer;
    FButtonPos: array of TRect;
    FButtonSize: TSize;
    FDown: boolean;
    PrevButtonIndex: integer;
    PrevState: integer;
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure SetRating(const Rating: integer);
    procedure SetSpacing(const Spacing: integer);
    procedure SetNumStars(const NumStars: integer);
    procedure SwapBuffers;
    procedure SetState(const ButtonIndex: integer; const State: integer);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer;
      Y: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer;
      Y: Integer); override;

  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    { Public declarations }
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
    property Rating: integer read FRating write SetRating default 3;
    property Spacing: integer read FSpacing write SetSpacing default DEFAULT_SPACING;
    property NumStars: integer read FNumStars write SetNumStars default DEFAULT_NUM_STARS;
    property OnDblClick;
    property OnKeyUp;
    property OnKeyPress;
    property OnKeyDown;
    property OnMouseWheelDown;
    property OnMouseWheelUp;
    property OnMouseWheel;
    property OnMouseEnter;
    property OnMouseLeave;
    property OnMouseActivate;
    property OnMouseMove;
    property OnMouseUp;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnClick;
    property Align;
    property Anchors;
    property Color;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses Math;

function IsIntInInterval(x, xmin, xmax: integer): boolean; inline;
begin
  IsIntInInterval := (xmin <= x) and (x <= xmax);
end;

function PointInRect(const X, Y: integer; const Rect: TRect): boolean; inline;
begin
  PointInRect := IsIntInInterval(X, Rect.Left, Rect.Right) and
                 IsIntInInterval(Y, Rect.Top, Rect.Bottom);
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Rejbrand 2009', [TStarRatingControl]);
end;

{ TStarRatingControl }

constructor TStarRatingControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  FBuffer := TBitmap.Create;
  FRating := 3;
  FSpacing := DEFAULT_SPACING;
  FNumStars := DEFAULT_NUM_STARS;
  SetLength(FButtonStates, FNumStars);
  SetLength(FButtonPos, FNumStars);
  for i := 0 to high(FButtonStates) do
    FButtonStates[i] := RBS_NORMAL;
  FDown := false;
  PrevButtonIndex := -1;
  PrevState := -1;
end;

destructor TStarRatingControl.Destroy;
begin
  FBuffer.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TStarRatingControl.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  inherited;
  FDown := true;
  for i := 0 to FNumStars - 1 do
    if PointInRect(X, Y, FButtonPos[i]) then
    begin
      SetState(i, RBS_PUSHED);
      Exit;
    end;
end;

procedure TStarRatingControl.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  if FDown then Exit;
  for i := 0 to FNumStars - 1 do
    if PointInRect(X, Y, FButtonPos[i]) then
    begin
      SetState(i, RBS_HOT);
      Exit;
    end;
  SetState(-1, -1);
end;

procedure TStarRatingControl.MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  for i := 0 to FNumStars - 1 do
    if PointInRect(X, Y, FButtonPos[i]) and (i = PrevButtonIndex) and (FRating <> i + 1) then
    begin
      SetRating(i + 1);
      if Assigned(FOnChange) then
        FOnChange(Self);
    end;
  FDown := false;
  MouseMove(Shift, X, Y);
end;

procedure TStarRatingControl.Paint;
var
  t: HTHEME;
  i: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  FBuffer.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  FBuffer.Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  FButtonSize := FALLBACK_BUTTON_SIZE;

  if UseThemes then
  begin

    t := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'BUTTON');
    if t <> 0 then
      try

        GetThemePartSize(t, FBuffer.Canvas.Handle, BP_RADIOBUTTON, RBS_NORMAL, nil, TS_DRAW, FButtonSize);

        for i := 0 to FNumStars - 1 do
          with FButtonPos[i] do
          begin
            Left := i * (Spacing + FButtonSize.cx);
            Top := (Self.Height - FButtonSize.cy) div 2;
            Right := Left + FButtonSize.cx;
            Bottom := Top + FButtonSize.cy;
          end;

        for i := 0 to FNumStars - 1 do
          DrawThemeBackground(t,
                              FBuffer.Canvas.Handle,
                              BP_RADIOBUTTON,
                              IfThen(FRating > i, RBS_CHECKEDNORMAL) + FButtonStates[i],
                              FButtonPos[i],
                              nil);

      finally
        CloseThemeData(t);
      end;

  end
  else
  begin

    for i := 0 to FNumStars - 1 do
      with FButtonPos[i] do
      begin
        Left := i * (Spacing + FButtonSize.cx);
        Top := (Self.Height - FButtonSize.cy) div 2;
        Right := Left + FButtonSize.cx;
        Bottom := Top + FButtonSize.cy;
      end;

    for i := 0 to FNumStars - 1 do
      DrawFrameControl(FBuffer.Canvas.Handle,
                       FButtonPos[i],
                       DFC_BUTTON,
                       DFCS_BUTTONRADIO or IfThen(FRating > i, DFCS_CHECKED));

  end;

  SwapBuffers;

end;

procedure TStarRatingControl.SetNumStars(const NumStars: integer);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  if FNumStars <> NumStars then
  begin
    FNumStars := NumStars;
    SetLength(FButtonStates, FNumStars);
    SetLength(FButtonPos, FNumStars);
    for i := 0 to high(FButtonStates) do
      FButtonStates[i] := RBS_NORMAL;
    Paint;
  end;
end;

procedure TStarRatingControl.SetRating(const Rating: integer);
begin
  if FRating <> Rating then
  begin
    FRating := Rating;
    Paint;
  end;
end;

procedure TStarRatingControl.SetSpacing(const Spacing: integer);
begin
  if FSpacing <> Spacing then
  begin
    FSpacing := Spacing;
    Paint;
  end;
end;

procedure TStarRatingControl.SetState(const ButtonIndex, State: integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to FNumStars - 1 do
    if i = ButtonIndex then
      FButtonStates[i] := State
    else
      FButtonStates[i] := RBS_NORMAL;

  if (PrevButtonIndex <> ButtonIndex) or (PrevState <> State) then
    Paint;

  PrevButtonIndex := ButtonIndex;
  PrevState := State;

end;

procedure TStarRatingControl.SwapBuffers;
begin
  BitBlt(Canvas.Handle,
         0,
         0,
         Width,
         Height,
         FBuffer.Canvas.Handle,
         0,
         0,
         SRCCOPY);
end;

procedure TStarRatingControl.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_SIZE:
      begin
        FBuffer.SetSize(Width, Height);
        Paint;
      end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Just adjust the properties `NumStars`, `Rating`, and `Spacing`, and have fun!

[image: Rating Control]

Of course, you could also write a component that uses custom bitmaps instead of the native Windows radio buttons.

Comment: +1 Nice work as usual, but it really looks pretty hopeless with radio buttons; please somebody find some stars!!

Comment: Yes. Just find a star PNG, include it in the resources and draw this (possibly with "hot" and "pushed" variants) instead of the radio buttons. Most of the logic can be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

Making radio buttons that look like radio buttons but behave differently would confuse the user. Also, you would end up needing half-check marks when you decide to display existing ratings. So something like a progress bar (maybe custom-colored or custom-drawn) to display, how "complete" user satisfaction is could be a better option.

Comment: These are discrete integer values, 1-5 and "not rated". A trackbar might work, but it requires more effort to use, and the VCL trackbar is too large for the application UI. (In fact, while I dislike all skinned apps and non-standard libraries like VGScene in general, I've come to understand why they exist. I'm finding it surprisingly hard to design a good-looking UI for the radio player with plain VCL controls only. Never had a problem like this with typical desktop utility apps.)

Comment: @moodforaday it's not VCL to blame, but Windows concept of UI unification, taking roots in 80's. So the UI was designed to let you provide uniform experience. If you want custom experience, use custom controls. In the opposite, on Android the UIs are highly customizable - regular OS control (eg. button) can be completely customized in XML or in runtime. That's just how the platform was designed ...

Comment: @eugene - and note that Windows also is highly customizable.  It's just that it also provides elements that are standardised *IF* that's what you want (or your users expect).  You don't get a customized UI on Android without putting some work in yourself to do the customization.... the same is simply also true on Windows.

Comment: @Deltics I developed ElPack replacement controls 10 years ago, and I *know* how bad Windows is in customization. Also you are wrong about android - it's customizable from the beginning: you declare appearance in XML and you can declare it the way you need, without hacks and tricks. I.e. there's no difference between "standard" and rounded-bordered button. Now try to declare a rounded-bordered button in Win32 API.

Comment: @Eugene - something is lost in translation I think.... customisABLE doesn't mean customISED.  I'm not saying it isn't customISAbLE from the start, I'm saying it isn't customISED from the start - it can't be.  CustomISATION is what makes it customISED and customISATION takes work.  Sure, it may be easier than on Windows, but Windows GUI's *ARE* customISABLE.  Also, the mechanism is different - to create a custom GUI in Windows requires coding, not declarations.  To say or simply that Windows isn't while Android is, is simply wrong.  Android is differently customisable, that's all.

Comment: @Deltics Windows GUIs are not completely customizable unlike Android. You can argue with me, of course, but this is solely your belief, while we completely disassembled and re-created windows theme engine ourselves for ElPack, so we have extensive experience with this. Coding won't be enough - there are places (like menus in Windows) where you can't do any customization but create your own control.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Eugene and Craig that something like stars would be better, but, to answer the question posed:

The unthemed radio button images are available by calling [LoadBitmap with OBM_CHECKBOXES](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/67709).  You can assign that directly to a TBitmap's `Handle` property, and then divide the width by 4 and the height by 3 to get the subbitmap measurements.  Use `TCanvas.BrushCopy` to do the drawing.

To draw the themed images you need to use Delphi's `Themes.pas`.  Specifically call `ThemeServices.GetElementDetails` with `tbRadioButtonUncheckedNormal` or `tbRadioButtonCheckedNormal` and pass the result to `ThemeServices.DrawElement` along with the client rect.

Here's a simple override that makes a TCheckBox draw as a checked radio button so you can see how it works:

```
TCheckBox = class(StdCtrls.TCheckBox)
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
end;

constructor TCheckBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  ControlState := ControlState + [csCustomPaint];
end;

procedure TCheckBox.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
  ThemeServices.DrawElement(DC,
    ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(tbRadioButtonCheckedNormal), ClientRect);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could place each radiobutton on a separate (tiny) panel, and that would make a substitute for the missing GroupIndex property.

Maybe not the nicest method, still relatively cheap, it seems to me.

Comment: Exactly. All radio buttons in the ["same container"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StdCtrls.TRadioButton.Checked) act as a group, so to suppress that behavior, simply put them in different containers.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks. My suggestion looks really somewhat obscure without an explanation (some general one at least).

Answer (score 0):

Good inspiration gave you Andreas Rejbrand (+1). I'll provide you just [some small piece of code](http://www.edisk.cz/stahni/16966/StarBar.zip_613.37KB.html) of what you are probably looking for. It's form with two overlapped images with one common event - OnMouseDown. It contains just some mad formula - unfortunately with constants, which I've made some time ago. But sorry I'm not mathematician, so please be patient with me and let's take this also as the inspiration :)